# Как встроить скрипты в html\css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Учусь делать сайт на HTML\CSS и меня попросили встроить пару скриптов(время,дата). Порылся в инете, так и не понял как встроить их в мой сайт.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 outline: none;
}

html {height: 100%}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #333;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
 line-height: 135%;
 
}

a {
 color: #f48b8b;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all.6s ease;
 -moz-transition: all.6s ease;
     
}

a:hover {
 color: #8b9ff5;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all.6s ease;
 -moz-transition: all.6s ease;    
}

a:active {color: #8ce4a6}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto\9;
}

.clear {clear: both}
.left {float: left}
.right {float: right}

/* Selection Block */

::selection {background: #f58b8b; color:#fff}
::-moz-selection {background: #f58b8b; color:#fff}

header, footer {
 width: 98%;
 background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
}

header {
 border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
 padding: 1%;
}

#logo {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif;
 color: silver; 
}

.contact {
 font-size 1.7 em;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type=search].field {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}


input[type=search].field:focus { 
 border: 2px solid #f58b8b; 
}

#menu {
 color: #666;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1.7em;
}

#menu hr {
 width: 500px;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menuHrefs a {
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 color: #626262;
}

#menuHrefs a:hover {
 background-color: #ececec; 
}


/* Main style */

#wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
#wrapper #articles {
 loat: left;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 
}

#wrapper #articles article {
 float: left;
 width: 31.3%;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 margin-right: 2%;
 min-height: 300px; 
}

#wrapper #articles article img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrapper #articles article h2 {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 color: #4a4a4a;
}

#wrapper #articles article p {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 text-indent: 0.5em;
}

#wrapper #articles article a {
 padding: 10px 10px;
 background-color: #ed7b7b;
 margin-left: 5%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 line-height: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrapper #articles article a:hover {
 background-color: #7feb6d;
 
}

/* Style about.html */

#about_us {
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 1%;
}

#columRight {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 5%;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 1%;
}

/* feedback */

form {
 width: 60%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 float: left;
}

form label {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 width: 40%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input:focus,form textarea:focus {border: 2px solid #f58b8b;}
 

 

form textarea {
 width: 60;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 
}

form #send {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #fa8764;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #fff;
}


form #send:hover {
 background-color: #f1f37a;
}

/* Main_Block */

#Main_soc_block {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2% 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
 border-top: 2px solid silver;
 margin: 20px 0;
 float: left;
 background: url('../image/MyCollages.png') repeat-x center 0;
 height: 220px;
 backround-color: silver;
    opacity: 0.7;  
}

#Main_soc_block_in {
 
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 border-radius: 7px;
 width: 500px;
 
}

#Main_soc_block_in a {
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #e9af32;
 border-radius: 6px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 
}

/* Style Footer */

#content {
 padding-bottom: 90px;
}
#footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color:#CFCFCF; 
 width:100%;   
 height: 90px;
 color: #212121;
 text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="test, site, website" />
<meta name="description" content="Сайт отечественных автомобилей" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="image/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Русское Авто</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
<header>
<a href="index.html" title="Главная" id="logo">
Russian-Auto</a>
<span class="contact">
<a href="about.html" title="Информация о нас">О нас</a></span>
<input type="search"class="field" placeholder="Поиск"/>
<span class="right"><span class="contact">
<a href="reg.html" title="Зарегестрироваться">Регистрация</a></span><span class="contact">
<a href="auth.html" title="Войти">Вход</a></span></span>
</header>


<div class="clear"><br /></div>
<center>
    <div id="menu">Разделы<hr /></div> 
    <div id="menuHrefs">
      <a href="about.html">О нас</a>
   <a href="feedback.html">Связь с нами</a>
   <a href="auth.html">Вход</a>
   <a href="reg.html">Регистрация</a>
 </div>
</center>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="articles">
        <article>
          <img src="image/firm.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" /> 
   <h2>Новости</h2>
   <p>Самые свежие новости отечественного автопрома.</p>
   <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
  </article>
  <article>
     <img src="image/opisanie.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" />
     <h2>Русский автопром</h2>
     <p>Отечественный автопром. Что, где, когда? Интересные факты и описание машин.</p>
     <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
  </article>
  <article>
     <img src="image/photo.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" />
     <h2>Галерея</h2>
     <p>Фото самыйх крутых и красивых машин от нас и наших пользователей.</p>
     <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
  </article>
    </div>
 <div class="clear">
    <div id="Main_soc_block">
 <center>
        <div id="Main_soc_block_in">
  <h3>Регистрируйтесь на сайте
  <p>Лучший сайт о российском автопроме</p>
  <a href="reg.html" title="Регистрируйтесь">Регистрируйтесь</a> 
    </div>
 </center>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<span class="left">Все права защищены &copy; 2019</span>
<span class="right">Группа в ВК https://vk.com/</span>
<span class="center">Контактный номер: 322-22-22</span>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие именно скрипты вы хотитие встроить?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"><!--
var date = new Date();
var d  = date.getDate();
var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

document.write(day + "." + month + "." + year + " г.");
 //--></script>   вот такие простые часы (скопировал код с сайта)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### JavaScript  подключается к HTML страничкам следующими способами

**Первый способ**

- Располагаете файл со скриптом где вам угодно(где-нибудь в папке с
  проектом буднт удобнее).
- В хедере html прописываете путь к файлу со скриптом

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
      ...
      <script src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
      ...
  </head>
  ...
  ...
  </html>
  ```

  Путь можно прописать как от корневой директории, так и относительно текущего html файла

**Второй способ**

- Встраиваете JS непосредственно в HTML посредством тэга `script`

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
      <body>
          ...
          <script>
              alert("It works!");
          </script>
          ...
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

После этих действияй скрипт будет срабатывать при переходе на страницу

Answer (score 0):

Просто в самом конце, перед закрытием тега html вставляете кусок.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 outline: none;
}

html {height: 100%}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #333;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
 line-height: 135%;
 
}

a {
 color: #f48b8b;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all.6s ease;
 -moz-transition: all.6s ease;
     
}

a:hover {
 color: #8b9ff5;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all.6s ease;
 -moz-transition: all.6s ease;    
}

a:active {color: #8ce4a6}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto\9;
}

.clear {clear: both}
.left {float: left}
.right {float: right}

/* Selection Block */

::selection {background: #f58b8b; color:#fff}
::-moz-selection {background: #f58b8b; color:#fff}

header, footer {
 width: 98%;
 background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
}

header {
 border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
 padding: 1%;
}

#logo {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif;
 color: silver; 
}

.contact {
 font-size 1.7 em;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type=search].field {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}


input[type=search].field:focus { 
 border: 2px solid #f58b8b; 
}

#menu {
 color: #666;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1.7em;
}

#menu hr {
 width: 500px;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menuHrefs a {
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 color: #626262;
}

#menuHrefs a:hover {
 background-color: #ececec; 
}


/* Main style */

#wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
#wrapper #articles {
 loat: left;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 
}

#wrapper #articles article {
 float: left;
 width: 31.3%;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 margin-right: 2%;
 min-height: 300px; 
}

#wrapper #articles article img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrapper #articles article h2 {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 color: #4a4a4a;
}

#wrapper #articles article p {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 text-indent: 0.5em;
}

#wrapper #articles article a {
 padding: 10px 10px;
 background-color: #ed7b7b;
 margin-left: 5%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 line-height: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrapper #articles article a:hover {
 background-color: #7feb6d;
 
}

/* Style about.html */

#about_us {
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 1%;
}

#columRight {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 5%;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 1%;
}

/* feedback */

form {
 width: 60%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 float: left;
}

form label {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 width: 40%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input:focus,form textarea:focus {border: 2px solid #f58b8b;}
 

 

form textarea {
 width: 60;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: 2px solid silver;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 
}

form #send {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #fa8764;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #fff;
}


form #send:hover {
 background-color: #f1f37a;
}

/* Main_Block */

#Main_soc_block {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2% 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
 border-top: 2px solid silver;
 margin: 20px 0;
 float: left;
 background: url('../image/MyCollages.png') repeat-x center 0;
 height: 220px;
 backround-color: silver;
    opacity: 0.7;  
}

#Main_soc_block_in {
 
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: 1px solid silver;
 border-radius: 7px;
 width: 500px;
 
}

#Main_soc_block_in a {
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #e9af32;
 border-radius: 6px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 
}

/* Style Footer */

#content {
 padding-bottom: 90px;
}
#footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color:#CFCFCF; 
 width:100%;   
 height: 90px;
 color: #212121;
 text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="test, site, website" />
  <meta name="description" content="Сайт отечественных автомобилей" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="image/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Русское Авто</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" title="Главная" id="logo">
Russian-Auto</a>
      <span class="contact">
<a href="about.html" title="Информация о нас">О нас</a></span>
      <input type="search" class="field" placeholder="Поиск" />
      <span class="right">
        <span class="contact">
          <a href="reg.html" title="Зарегестрироваться">Регистрация</a>
        </span>
        <span class="contact">
          <a href="auth.html" title="Войти">Вход</a>
        </span>
        <span class="contact">
          <a id="timeText">Время: 00:00</a>
        </span>
        
      </span>
    </header>

    <div class="clear"><br /></div>
    <center>
      <div id="menu">Разделы
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div id="menuHrefs">
        <a href="about.html">О нас</a>
        <a href="feedback.html">Связь с нами</a>
        <a href="auth.html">Вход</a>
        <a href="reg.html">Регистрация</a>
      </div>
    </center>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="articles">
        <article>
          <img src="image/firm.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" />
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <p>Самые свежие новости отечественного автопрома.</p>
          <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img src="image/opisanie.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" />
          <h2>Русский автопром</h2>
          <p>Отечественный автопром. Что, где, когда? Интересные факты и описание машин.</p>
          <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <img src="image/photo.jpg" alt="Изображение" title="Изображение" />
          <h2>Галерея</h2>
          <p>Фото самыйх крутых и красивых машин от нас и наших пользователей.</p>
          <a href="/article" title="Посмотреть статью">Читать</a>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
        <div id="Main_soc_block">
          <center>
            <div id="Main_soc_block_in">
              <h3>Регистрируйтесь на сайте
                <p>Лучший сайт о российском автопроме</p>
                <a href="reg.html" title="Регистрируйтесь">Регистрируйтесь</a>
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <span class="left">Все права защищены &copy; 2019</span>
      <span class="right">Группа в ВК https://vk.com/</span>
      <span class="center">Контактный номер: 322-22-22</span>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
  var yy = date.getYear();
  var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
  document.querySelector("#timeText").textContent = (day + "." + month + "." + year + " г.");
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Да, действительно сработало. А как добавить класс этому скрипту? Чтобы в CSS ему стили задать (вверху сайта надо его)

Comment: Желательно чтобы часы были в шапке сайта. Для этого нужно в css стили задавать, или просто можно в header e html прописать скрипт?

Comment: @АлексейИванов В данном случае в самом скрипте написано, что к документу(сайте) просто добавляется текст(не html элемент). Сейчас дополню ответ(покажу как разместить в шапке)

Comment: @АлексейИванов Готово, теперь время в шапке. Я изменил скрипт и создал в html новый элемент в шапке. Скрипт теперь просто изменяет текст внутри готового элемента.

Comment: Спасибо больше, всё работает.